# Blank space after editing a post by the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, edits, android-app

I edited [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450780/using-logical-or-not-and-in-jsoup-selectors) using the Stack Exchange Android app, and it showed me blank space between the title and tags. For a minute I was surprised and thought I did a wrong edit. Here is a screenshot.

**Device Information**: [Google Nexus 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_4) with [Android 4.4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_4.4_KitKat_.28API_level_19.29) (KitKat).

**PS:** Here is the [edit history to show that I actually made a valid edit.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15450780/revisions)

[image].